# KVC Compliance - Guidelines for declaring iVars

Tags: ios, cocoa, kvc

I have seen *ivars* that are backing properties declared in 2 general formats (in various books, on blogs, etc...) :

```
myProperty = _myProperty;
myProperty = myProperty_;
```

Apple docs say the former one is needed for [key value compliance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002172-BAJEAIEE)

Which one is most appropriate ?

Comment: Thanks for that - I think it needs clarifying that the documentation in fact says that KVC will look for properly named accessor methods first, and _then_ for an ivar named key or _key. That does not mean that naming your ivars _key is required for KVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The currently informal recommendation from Apple is to use an underscore prefix. There are [indications](http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2012/Jan/msg00011.html) that there will be syntactic conveniences for this in future.

Answer (score 2):

If you're creating a property, the name of the underlying ivar doesn't make any difference to KVC — it will go through the accessor. It will only access the instance variable if **both** of the following are true:

- It can't find any appropriate accessor for the key
- The object's class returns `YES` for `accessInstanceVariablesDirectly`